# How do I deserialize object variables using Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson

I have a `Packet` class, which serializes and deserializes fine:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Packet.Builder.class)
public final class Packet {
    // Constructors, getters, etc
    // ...
    public static final class Builder {
        // Builder variables...
        // ...

        @JsonProperty("value_date")
        public Builder valueDate(String val) {
            valueDate = val;
            return this;
        }

        @JsonProperty("generation_date")
        public Builder generationTimeStamp(String val) {
            generationTimeStamp = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Packet build() { return new Packet(this); }
    }
```

I also have a `PacketResponse` object, which looks like:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = PacketResponse.Builder.class)
public final class PacketResponse {

    // Packet and response message
    private final String message;
    private final Packet packet;

    // Constructors, getters, etc
    // ...

    public static final class Builder {

        private Packet packet;
        private String message;

        private Builder() {}

        @JsonProperty("packet")
        public Builder packet(Packet val) {
            packet = val;
            return this;
        }

        @JsonProperty("message")
        public Builder message(String val) {
            message = val;
            return this;
        }

        public PacketResponse build() {
            return new PacketResponse(this);
        }
    }
```

The serialization of `PacketResponse` objects works fine, and results in:

```
{
    "message": "the quick brown fox",
    "packet": {
        "valueDate": "2015-10-24",
        "generationTimeStamp": "2015-11-12T20:45:24+0000"
    }
}
```

**However**, when I try to deserialize this JSON back into a `PacketResponse` object, using

```
new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, PacketResponse.class);
```

I get an `Unrecognized field "valueDate" (class com.m.Packet$Builder), not marked as ignorable`.

It seems like it's trying to deserialize `Packet` but because it isn't doing it directly Jackson can't see the `@JsonProperty("value_date")` annotation and instead is looking for a `valueDate` field (since that's the name of the builder method).

Can anyone help me figure out the right way to deserialize the JSON? I'm still new to Jackson and don't really know how to resolve this.

Comment: Just curious and hoping to learn something: what is the purpose of the Builder class?

Comment: I want `Packet` objects to be able to be built using JSON or programmatically, hence the Builder class EDIT: same reasoning for the `Response` object

Comment: Cool, didn't know Jackson had support for the builder pattern.

Comment: @dnault it's pretty useful, as long as you remember to annotate things correctly and have a `.build()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON contains "valueDate" but the @JsonProperty annotation specifies "value_date" (with an underscore).

Ditto "generation_date" in the annotation vs "generationTimeStamp" in the JSON.

Comment: yup this was it! thanks! I added `@JsonGetter("value_date")` to my getters in `Packet` and that solved it